# Jar file (downloaded as .zip extension) wont open

Tags: java, jar

I've downloaded a file, which is supposed to be a .jar file, but it was standard a .zip file. If I open the file with winzip, it shows following folders and files:

- META-INF (folder)
- resources (folder)
- Action.class
- Main.class
- Updater.class

With my knowledge, I think this is a legit .jar file, but somehow I can't open it.

I tried to google the question, and tried these methods:

- Opening it with Commandpromp (as admin) and run it with `java -jar <file>`
- Open with another program, and pointing it to my javaw.exe, java.exe, or any other .exe file in C:\program files (x86)\java\jre7\bin... (Gives me a commandpromp that crashes after a few seconds, I tried to take a print-screen and it said: "could not find or load main class")

But all didn't work. My java environment is up to date. Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm on a windows 8.1 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems what you mean by *open it* is *run it*. But a jar file can be run if it contains a class with a **main** method. Many jars don't (they are just libraries, not supposed to be run on their own).

Comment: Ok, I get that, and how can I add a main method, or external software for it in order to run?

Comment: @NickPeelman here is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) that explains, how you specify the main class in the mamifest file of the jar.

Answer (score 0):

The Jar you have is likely a library, the error you are getting states that the JVM cannot find the entry point for the application (i.e. `public static void main(String[] args) {}`.